# how to get Firebase ServerValue.Timestamp in Long using POJO Class

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I am loading TimeStamp value using getDateLastChangedLong method it gives an NullPointerException .How can i convert it into Long.[image: bUTTON cLICK]
[image: Exception]

[image: Date Uploaded[![][2]]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GEWj.jpg)

Comment: I am not sure but I think the type of date should be a long as it is a unix timestamp instead of Object and the getter and setter for `date`  field should be `getDate` and `setDate` instead of any other method name like you have given `getDateLastChangeLong`

Answer (score 0):

In order to set a `TIMESTAMP` in a Firebase database, you need to declare the field as a `Map` and not as an Object as i see you did and then use `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` like this:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
yourRef.child("yourNode").updateChildren(map);
```

Remember, when you are setting the `TIMESTAMP` in the Firebase database, you are setting it as a `Map` and when you are retrieving it, you are retrieving it as a `long`.

Your POJO class should look like this:

```
public class ImageUpload {
    private Map<String, String> timeStamp;
    //other fields

    public Map<String, String> getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }

    public void setTimeStamp(Map<String, String> timeStamp) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

    //other setters and getters.
}
```

In order to get the timestamp using the public getter `getTimeStamp()`, you need to attach a listener on `ImageUpload` node and iterate the data from the `dataSnapshot` object.

If you want also to convert the data back, i suggest you using the following metod:

```
public static String getTimeDate(long timeStamp){
    try{
        DateFormat dateFormat = getDateTimeInstance();
        Date netDate = (new Date(timeStamp));
        return dateFormat.format(netDate);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return "date";
    }
}
```

Comment: But I want to retrieve it from POJO rather than from firebase database

Comment: The POJO is a mirror of your database. With other other words the POJO helper class helps to get the from the database. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: The getter method will be retreiveing key as well as value or just value.

Comment: The `getTimeStamp()` will retrieve only the value as `long`. As soon as you have the the value, you can convert it using the method above.

Comment: I want to insert timestamp into firebase databse using imageUpload constructor.Will u please edit the code